# Combine 2 solutions and share modules between solutions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have two solutions in VS2012 that I just merged. That went well, however, I have a module on solution 2 that I would also like for solution 2 to access. How can 2 solutions share resources. I have not used VS2012 for long so I do not know how this can be done.

If any can point me in the right direction, I will appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not 100% clear on what you have done so far, perhaps you can elaborate, maybe with some screenshots. You may want to look into creating a class library and share that between multiple solutions, via DLL or project reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your file is in solution 1. Open Solution 2, rt-click the project you want to add to and select 'Add',  'Existing Item'. Browse to the file, then on the 'Add' button, extend the drop-down and click 'Add as link'